# Run commandline on multiple files in folder

Tags: command-line, vbscript

I'd like to have a simple vbscript or even just a commandline one-liner that allows me to (in pseudocode):

```
for each file FL (*.ts) in folder
   run command 'ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams 1 -print_format csv -i "folder\FL" > "folder\FL.Name.csv"'
next
```

Like the code says, I only want it to work on files of type .TS, and I need to run each file in the folder through that commandline and redirect the stdout to a csv file.  I could create a small program in C#, but I'd rather have a lightweight script or something and I'm new to that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Processing files with a particular extension in a given folder can be done like this:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\foo").Files
  If fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "ts" Then
    sh.Run "...", 0, True
  End If
Next
```

Redirecting the output to a CSV file is (IMHO) best done by running the VBScript with `cscript.exe` and redirecting STDOUT to a file:

```
cscript your.vbs > output.csv
```

Comment: Example not completed. What to run? fso? f? how?

Comment: @Alex Wow, you went and downvoted the answer for *that*? Seriously? Because I totally feel like answering your questions now...

Comment: The answer is not complete. It's a standard way to proceed in the site. I was looking yesterday for a way to solve a similar problem, as a newbie in VB and this answer was not useful to me. I.e. the sh.Run should be followed by parenthesis... This little things are what makes this site so popular. But of course, revise your answer and I'll revise my vote.

Comment: @Alex As a matter of fact the argument list of `sh.Run` MUST NOT be in parentheses here. And I have nothing to add to my answer WRT the question at hand.